# Is pivot_longer() and pivot_wider() transitive?

Tags: r, tidyr

I wanted to use function pivot_longer() and pivot_wider() for iris dataset. This is the code to lengthen the data:

```
iris_ds <- iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species, names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value")
```

In the documentation it says that pivot_wider() is the inverse transformation of pivot_longer(), so I apply the code:

```
iris_or <- iris_ds %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "Measure", values_from = "Value")
```

and I get the following table:

```
    Species    Sepal.Length      Sepal.Width    Petal.Length    Petal.Width
    setosa     <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
    versicolor <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
    virginica  <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
```

This was answered in the gather() spread() similar question (using a RowId was suggested), the help I want is if the new functions pivot_longer and pivot_wider have a way to manage this to make it transitive. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can add `%>% unnest` to the end to get back to the original dimensions

Comment: Hello @IceCreamToucan, I tried your proposal and it gave me the original dataset, just with a warning, saying cols is now required. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, there's nothing within `pivot_*` to address this. Might be a good idea to add something in the future to `pivot_longer` to generate unique rowIDs from within.

As you said, the workaround is to add such row IDs yourself, using `tibble`'s `rowid_to_column`:

```
iris %>% rowid_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species,rowid), names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Measure", values_from = "Value")
```

this will bring you back to iris.